# Extracting data from one DataFrame to another

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a DataFrame `data`:

|  | Date | 1Y | 2Y | 3Y | 4Y | 5Y | 6Y | 7Y | 8Y | 9Y | 10Y | C0 | C1 | C2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2006-01-06 | 1.6630 | 1.8605 | 2.0481 | 2.2259 | 2.3937 | 2.5517 | 2.6998 | 2.8380 | 2.9664 | 3.0848 | 7.392170 | 2.451846 | -0.100585 |
| 1 | 2006-01-09 | 1.6531 | 1.8483 | 2.0339 | 2.2099 | 2.3762 | 2.5329 | 2.6800 | 2.8174 | 2.9452 | 3.0634 | 7.339621 | 2.433888 | -0.098956 |
| 2 | 2006-01-10 | 1.6436 | 1.8375 | 2.0220 | 2.1969 | 2.3624 | 2.5184 | 2.6649 | 2.8020 | 2.9295 | 3.0476 | 7.298496 | 2.421375 | -0.096909 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 1707 | 2012-11-05 | 2.9475 | 3.0809 | 3.0869 | 3.1859 | 3.2060 | 3.4211 | 3.4938 | 3.5200 | 3.5517 | 3.5872 | 9.900536 | 2.556375 | -0.542565 |
| 1708 | 2012-11-06 | 2.9438 | 3.0764 | 3.0857 | 3.1748 | 3.2000 | 3.4305 | 3.5040 | 3.5223 | 3.5459 | 3.5771 | 9.894910 | 2.557064 | -0.545739 |

Now I have another DataFrame `divis` which contains following values:

|  | Starting Date | Ending Date | Period |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2006-01-06 | 2006-07-28 | 203 days |
| 1 | 2006-07-28 | 2006-10-20 | 84 days |
| 2 | 2006-10-20 | 2007-01-19 | 91 days |
| 3 | 2007-01-19 | 2007-07-13 | 175 days |
| 4 | 2007-07-13 | 2007-11-23 | 133 days |

What I need to do now is to find in `data` the values of C0, C1 and C2 on the starting and ending dates listed in `divis`, and append these data to `divis`. For example, look at the first row of `divis`. The Starting Date is 2006-01-06, so I move to `data`, find the row of 2006-01-06, which is the first row, get the value C0 on that row(7.392170) and append it on the first row of `divis`. Again for the ending date, I get

|  | Starting Date | Ending Date | Period | Starting C0 | Ending C0 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2006-01-06 | 2006-07-28 | 203 days | 7.392170 | 8.437521 |

How to carry out this data-fetching process automatically with Python? Thank you in advance!

Comment: @Guy How to present a table in a post...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is this:

```
#Set the date column as the index in table 1. This would allow you to search values in O(1)
df1_indexed = df1.set_index("Date")

def date_getter(x):
    try:
        #search for the values 
        return pd.Series([df1_indexed.loc[x['Starting Date'],'C0'], df1_indexed.loc[x['Ending Date'],'C0']])
    except: #In case the dates weren't found.
        return pd.Series([np.nan,np.nan])


df2[['Starting C0','Ending C0']] = df2[['Starting Date', 'Ending Date']].apply(date_getter,axis=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
# here df represents the 'data' and df2 represents divis
for i in df2.index :
    x=(df[df['Date']==df2.loc[i,"Starting Date"]]['C0'].values[0])    
    y=(df[df['Date']==df2.loc[i,"Ending Date"]]['C0'].values[0])
    df2.loc[i,'Starting C0'] = x
    df2.loc[i,'Ending C0'] = y
```

Note : This code will work fine until all the dates in divis are present in data, otherwise an exception would be raised. In that case use try except to fill with null or default values or do let me know I'll provide the alternative code.

Comment: It is a very inefficient code. You are filtering the df for every row.

Comment: You are also doing the same thing in a different way. You are also applying the filter for each row. The difference is just that I've used a for loop and you have used apply function.

Comment: I am not filtering it. I have used indexing in df. That makes it behave like a map.

Comment: Also, for-loops in pandas are a bad practice. Should be avoided whenever you can. I am not saying this, I learnt it from jezrael. He is among the ones with the most reputation on SO.

Comment: Yeah loops doesn't provide computation efficiency. I'll try to avoid their use wherever possible.